Can I change my appearance later in the game without needing to start over?
I had already set my appearance when I created my character at the beginning of the game, but now I'd like to make my skin colour slightly darker and also change my hair colour.
Is this somehow possible or will I need to start over from scratch and create a brand new character?
If it is possible, then how/where? Also what kind of things can I change?

You can, but not everything. These elements are fixed once the game is started:

Body shape
Dormitory type (Witch or Wizard)
Face shape
Skin colour
Voice tone

To do so you need an hairdressing salon, like this:

You will have access to a character creation menu.
As you can see, you can only change haircut, hair colour, eyes shape, eyes colour, eyebrows, markings, moles and scars.


Ah. That's unfortunate that I can't change my skin colour as that's one of the main things I wanted to change. At least hair colour is available. Thank you!

@ShaunRoselt that makes the game kinda "realistic": one can always change their hairstyle but the skin colour is fixed for everyone

I don't fully agree here. I mean, If I were to sit in the sun for a couple of hours, then I would definitely have a different skin colour. I'd either be a little red or be more tanned.

@ShaunRoselt ok, a little tone. I mean, you can't turn from afroamerican to asian to caucasian in one day.
